# In triangle ABC, $\angle C$ is right angle. Find the maximum value of $\cos A.\cos B$.

Tags: trigonometry

In triangle ABC, $\angle C$ is right angle. Find the maximum value of $\cos A.\cos B$.

My attempt:
$\angle C=\dfrac {\pi}{2}$ then $\angle (A+B)=\dfrac {\pi}{2}$

Let $$y=\cos A.\cos B$$
$$=\cos A.\cos (\dfrac {\pi}{2}-A)$$
$$=\cos A.\sin A$$
So, $y=\dfrac {\sin (2A)}{2}$

Comment: So far so good. Now, it should not be difficult to find the maximum value of $y $: it is when $\sin 2A$ takes a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring the formulas
$$
\cos(x\pm y) = \cos(x)\cos(y) \mp\sin(x)\sin(y),
$$we derive
$$
\cos(A)\cos(B)= \frac{\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)}{2},
$$
and since $\cos(A+B)=\cos(\pi-C)=-\cos(C)$,
$$
\cos(A)\cos(B)= \frac{-\cos(C)+\cos(A-B)}{2},
$$
so the maximum is taken when $A-B=0$, that is $A=B=\dfrac{\pi-C}{2}$, and has the value $\dfrac{1-\cos(C)}{2}$.